# blit an image for a certain period in pygame

Tags: pygame

i want to keep an image on the background for lets say one second ( or more ) then it should disappear , i tried to use blit inside a function ( image_draw ) called inside if statement, but the image appeared for a very short time and if i change the the time of the image inside the function image_draw i didn't see any change.

in the code i have a thick line moving continuously to the right and to the left and every time it touches one of the frame border it changes its direction and an image appears when the direction change happened , my question is how can i control the time of the image on the background ? the function image_draw didn't help,  here is the code.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import math

from pygame.locals import *

def image_draw(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE, IMAGE_TIME ):
    while IMAGE_TIME > 0:
        windowSurface.blit(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE)
        IMAGE_TIME -= 1

pygame.init()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 600), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("line and image")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
MYCOLOR= (200, 240, 50)
OTHER_LINE_COLOR = (180, 0, 0)



OUR_LINE_START_X = 50
OUR_LINE_START_Y = 400
OUR_LINE_END_X = 250
OUR_LINE_END_Y = 400

OTHER_LINE_START_X = 0
OTHER_LINE_START_Y = 415
OTHER_LINE_END_X = 300
OTHER_LINE_END_Y = 415





IMAGE = pygame.image.load("cherry.png")
LEFT_IMAGE = 250
TOP_IMAGE = 530
WIDTH_IMAGE = 40
HIGHT_IMAGE = 40
IMAGE_TIME = 10
RECT_FOR_IMAGE_1 = pygame.Rect(LEFT_IMAGE, TOP_IMAGE, WIDTH_IMAGE, HIGHT_IMAGE)
RECT_FOR_IMAGE_2 = pygame.Rect(LEFT_IMAGE - 200, TOP_IMAGE, WIDTH_IMAGE, HIGHT_IMAGE)
SOUND = pygame.mixer.Sound("pickup.wav")

MOVE_SPEED = 1


DIRECTION = "left"



while True:
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE) 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()



    if DIRECTION == "right" :
        OUR_LINE_START_X += MOVE_SPEED
        OUR_LINE_END_X += MOVE_SPEED

    elif DIRECTION == "left":
        OUR_LINE_START_X -= MOVE_SPEED
        OUR_LINE_END_X -= MOVE_SPEED

    if OUR_LINE_START_X < 0:
        DIRECTION = "right"
        SOUND.play()
        image_draw(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE_1, IMAGE_TIME )


    if OUR_LINE_END_X > 300:
        DIRECTION = "left"
        SOUND.play()
        image_draw(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE_2, IMAGE_TIME )




    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, MYCOLOR, (OUR_LINE_START_X, OUR_LINE_START_Y), (OUR_LINE_END_X, OUR_LINE_END_Y), 30)
    pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, OTHER_LINE_COLOR, (OTHER_LINE_START_X, OTHER_LINE_START_Y), (OTHER_LINE_END_X, OTHER_LINE_END_Y), 3)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your while loop is the game frame loop.

When you draw using image_draw you are counting down from 10 to 0 within one frame and blitting the image then. Also because you are referencing the IMAGE_TIME variable from within the function with the same name the scope of the variable is only within that function.

visual description of what is happening:

```
Game Loop:
  draw_image:
    10 - 0
      blit
  next frame
```

To make this work properly you can leave the IMAGE_TIME variable out of the image_draw method signature and use the global IMAGE_TIME. Remove the while loop from image_draw and let it modify the global on each frame, then you would need to reset that when you wanted to draw the image again.

```
IMAGE_TIME = 10

def image_draw(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE):
  if IMAGE_TIME > 0:
    windowSurface.blit(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE)
    IMAGE_TIME -= 1

# ... other code left out for brevity

if OUR_LINE_START_X < 0:
    DIRECTION = "right"
    SOUND.play()
    if IMAGE_TIME == 0:
      IMAGE_TIME = 10
    image_draw(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE_1)


if OUR_LINE_END_X > 300:
    DIRECTION = "left"
    SOUND.play()
    if IMAGE_TIME == 0:
      IMAGE_TIME = 10
    image_draw(IMAGE, RECT_FOR_IMAGE_2)
```

It is also worth pointing out that the appropriate way to control framerate in pygame is to create a clock object and tick it with the desired frame rate:

```
clock = pygame.Clock()
while True:
  # do your stuff here
  clock.tick(60) # 60 frames per second
```

This means that the game loop will execute roughly 60 times every second so you can easily control the showing of the image to 1 second by setting `IMAGE_TIME = 60`.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel , you helped me to understand better what is going on in the code.

Comment: Hello,

Sorry to reopen, but I want to do the same thing, problem is it's inside mouse click event, so it don't loop to decrease IMAGE_TIME.

Any idea ?